# Series flow with Async in NodeJS gets asynchrounously called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I need to call 3 functions in series x1() then x2() then x3(). But since x1 and x2 are time consuming operations x3 executes before them giving unexpected results. I have used the `async` library in NodeJS with the `series` method as below.
How can I solve this without using `setTimeout` for x3()

```
async.series([function(callback) {  x1();callback(null, null);},
           function(callback) { x2();callback(null, null);},
            function(callback) { 
                 x3();
                callback(null, null); }],
            function(err, results) { }
    );
```

Comment: Try using module `async`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the callback function had to be overloaded with different number of arguments the best option was to structure the method as follows

```
function callback(cbargs){
    var arg1 = cbargs.cbarg1;
    var arg2 = cbargs.cbarg2;
    if(arg3!=null){
        .....  
    }
} 
function x1(arg1 , arg2, callback, cbargs){
     .....
     .....
     callback(cbargs);
}
function x3(arg1 , arg2, callback, cbargs){
     .....
     .....
     callback(cbargs);
}
x1(arg1, arg2,callback,{cbarg1, cbarg2});
x1(arg1, arg2,callback,{cbarg1, cbarg2, cbarg3});
```

Answer (score 1):

use recursive try catch..

```
a=true;
while(a){


try{

your work.....


a=false;


}catch(exp ){

a=true
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's async nature to solve it. Here how it's done with callbacks. Call `x3()` instead of `onMethodsDone()`.
Here, suppose x1() accepts an array. Forget it if you don't need any parameters. `x3()` gets the modified array from `x2()` which is also another time consuming function. `setTimeout()` is used to show the async behaviour since `x1()` and `x2()` are time consuming.

```
x1([1,2],function(results){
    x2(results,onMethodsDone);
});

function onMethodsDone(results){
    alert(results);
}

function x1(records,cb){
    setTimeout(function (){
        records.push(3,4,5);
        cb(records); //parse updated records to callback
    },2000);
}

function x2(records,cb){
    setTimeout(function (){
        records.push(6,7,8);
        cb(records);
    },2000);
}
```

javascripts Listeners or Promise/defers also can be used to handle it.